# Question about matrices and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

For two $n\times n$ square matrices $A$ and $B$ satisfying $AB=A+B,\;$
suppose $A$ has an eigenvector $u.$
 How to show that $u$ is also and eigenvector of $B?$

Comment: Show us what you tried please.

Comment: I tried from definition $Au=\lambda u$ and multiply both side by u i.e. ABu=Au+Bu, then Bu=ABu-Au=(AB-A)u. But I don’t know how to continue onward.

Comment: But AB doesnt have to equal BA

Comment: Also, it seems that proof by contradiction is not working (or I don’t know the way)

Comment: Well! Could you please enclose your comments above into your question?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: from the given condition show that $A-I$ and $B-I$ are inverse of each of each other. Then from the given equation solve for $B$.

It is easy to check that $(A-I)(B-I)=I$. Now $$(A-I)B=A. $$ Multiply bothsides by $B-I$ to get $$B= (B-I)A=BA-A.$$

You should be able to continue from here since now $AB= BA$.

Comment: Show $B=(A-I)^{-1}A=(B-I) A$.

Comment: If you have show that $(A−I)(B−I)=I$ it's enough. $A−I$ has the same eigenvectors as $A$ , $B−I$ as inverse the same as $A−I$ and $B$ the same as $B−I$

Comment: Nice observations, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the hint of @user9077, and without need of commutativity of $A,B,$ assume $(\lambda,v)\;$ is an eigenpair of $A.$ 
Then $$Bv=(B-I)Av=(B-I)\lambda v=\lambda B v- \lambda v$$ hence $$(1-\lambda)Bv=-\lambda v.$$ This means that $(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-1},v)$ is an eigenpair of $B.$

Answer (score 0):

*if two $n\times n$ matrix share a commutative association, then they would also share a common eigenvalues*
$$A\cdot B = A+B$$
although the multiplication of matrix is not commutative but its addition is, so its easy to see that
$$ A + B = B+A = AB = BA$$
$$AB =BA$$
so your matrix can be an example of one with oriented elements, check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4081212/properties-of-matrices-having-same-eigen-values/4081324#4081324/), then the eigenvalues of $A+B$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$