# Properties of matrices having same eigen values.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, universal-property

Let $ P=\begin{bmatrix}
  x & y & z\\
      \end{bmatrix} $
and $ M=\begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 2 & 3\\
         3 & 1 & 2\\
  2 & 3 & 1\\
  \end{bmatrix} $
and $ N=\frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}
         2 & 5 & 5\\
         5 & 2 & 5\\
  5 & 5 & 2\\
  \end{bmatrix} $

Here $PMP'=PNP' \nRightarrow N=M$, why?

Only two things I can see, first that matrix $M$ and $N$ commute that is $MN=NM$ and second, they have the same eigen values.

Is this reason enough? What is the name for this kind of matrices?

I have also tried to premultiply by $P'$ as:

$$PMP'=PNP' \\
  (P'P)MP'=(P'P)NP' \\
  MP'=NP' \\ 
\text{(roughly assuming that inverse of $PP'$ exists)}$$

But since $MP'\ne NP'$ so what I had assumed that $(PP')^{-1}$ exists is wrong in general. Is this always the case? Because $P$ is a general row-matrix.

Comment: The only property they share is the commutative multiplication, giving them equal determinants, which implies same eigenvalues

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua Sir the determinants are not the same.

Comment: If the determinants are not equal then the eigenvalue-sets are not equal.

Comment: Can you explain why this is surprising you? The condition $x^T M x=x^T N x$ for all $x$ imposes six conditions on the nine numbers $m_{ij}=n_{ij}$, that's not enough to guarantee equality when $i\not=j$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3037923/question-about-matrices-and-eigenvectors

Answer (score 1):

Same eigenvalues is different from common eigenvalues

The first matrix $M$ has eigenvalues of $[\omega_1 = -\frac{\sqrt(3) i+3}{2}, \omega_2 = \frac{\sqrt(3) i-3}{2}, \omega_3 = 6]$  While the second matrix $N$ has eigenvalues of $[\omega_1 = -\frac{3}{2}, \omega_2 = -\frac{3}{2} , \omega_3 = 6 ]$

By examination the two matrix there are made of $3$ elements, oriented in each row
$$M =
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&c\\
c&a&b\\
b&c&a\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$N =
\begin{pmatrix}
p&q&r\\
r&p&q\\
q&r&p\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Sir can you work out some of the properties or prove that the multiplication here is commutative
$$ M \cdot N = N \cdot M $$
Your matrix are another example of commutative matrix other than orthogonal matrixes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $Z_{3 \times 3}=P_{3\times 1}.P_{1\times 3}$, then $\det|Z|=0$.